# Выборка соседних записей с условием

Tags: mysql

Выводя запись на сайт, требуется выводить соседние записи этой же категории. Похожего на виджета "Похожие новости". (В моем случаи "Новости этой же категории")

Выбрать три новые записи отталкиваясь от главной записи, и две записи "старее" главной записи, но, если новых записей мало, тогда брать больше старых записей, и наоборот.
В итоге получится 5 соседних записей.

Comment: Вопрос имеет несколько направлений похожие по чем? По тексту по категории по датам итп. От этого и зависит ответ, самый сложный по записям, в данном примере нужна индексация базы и только тогда выбор.

Answer (score 0):

Типа так:

```
SELECT xx.*
FROM (    (    SELECT *, (@row:=@row+1) rn
               FROM table, (SELECT @row:=0) x
               WHERE table.date < @date
               ORDER BY table.date DESC
           )
           UNION ALL
           (   SELECT *, (@row:=@row+1) rn
               FROM table, (SELECT @row:=0) x
               WHERE table.date > @date
               ORDER BY table.date ASC
           )
           UNION ALL
           (   SELECT *, 0 rn
               FROM table
               WHERE table.date = @date
           )
     ) xx
ORDER BY xx.rn ASC
LIMIT 5
```

@date - нужная дата "базовой" записи.

Comment: охх, сильный запрос, еще бы понять куда подставить имена моих таблиц)

Comment: @Дмитрий По тексту вопроса речь идёт об одной таблице. В запросе используется три её копии, все имеют имя `table`.

Comment: Совершенно верно, а что означает "xx" внизу запроса?

Comment: Алиас подзапроса. Может быть почти любым - но быть обязан.